# Динамическое изменение шрифта элемента CStatic

Tags: mfc, c++

Подскажите, возможно ли динамически изменить шрифт (сделать жирным) CStatic контрола(текста), и, если возможно, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: А просто SetFont не работает?

Comment: Если просто использовать SetFont, изменятся все составляющие шрифта(если он был заранее задан) на значения по умолчанию. Хотелось бы изменить именно текущий шрифт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем простейший вариант - взять текущее значение шрифта, изменить его и заново переназначить шрифт элементу.

```
BOOL CStaticFontDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...

    // Get current font.
    CFont* pFont = GetDlgItem( IDC_STATIC_ITALIC )->GetFont();
    LOGFONT LogFont = { 0 };
    pFont->GetLogFont( &LogFont );

    // Create new font with underline style.
    LogFont.lfUnderline = TRUE;
    m_StaticFont.CreateFontIndirect( &LogFont );

    // Sets the new font back to static text.
    GetDlgItem( IDC_STATIC_ITALIC )->SetFont( &m_StaticFont );

    return TRUE;
}
```

Ссылка: http://weseetips.com/2009/03/04/how-to-set-font-for-static-text-controls/